# DevExpress grid Filter Expression is not updated

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview

I have applied criteria expression for header filter for ASPxGridView. Its working fine when the column alone filtered. And i have applied the expression to session and applied this session to grid.FilterExpression.

If I filter the other column along with this one its not working.i.e the expression applied to the session is not getting updated instead its appending with the older expression.

Comment: What is filter expression and how are you assigning.. Provide little information and faulty code snippet to understand the issue rather let every one guess about the implementation scenario.

Comment: Can you provide page markup and code behind to help reproduce your issue? What condition fulfills "session is not getting updated" then?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because of Dev express filter expression is not cleared so we made cleared in Auto Perform Callback method and its working good Thanks.